# Subset rows in list of dataframes using list of vectors of row positions

Tags: r, list, subset, lapply

I have a list of data frames:

```
data1 <-
data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    Name1 = c(3, 2, 3, 2),
    Name2 = c(4, 5, 4, 5),
    Name3 = c(6, 7, 6, 7),
    Name4 = c(8, 9, 8, 9))
data2 <-
data.frame(
    ID = c(2, 2, 2),
    Name4 = c(7, 3, 3),
    Name2 = c(3, 1, 1),
    Name3 = c(2, 2, 2),
    Name1 = c(1, 1, 1))
data3 <-
data.frame(
    ID = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    Name3 = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6),
    Name1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    Name4 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    Name2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
data4 <-
data.frame(
    ID = c(4, 4, 4, 4),
    Name2 = c(5, 7, 7, 5),
    Name3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    Name1 = c(9, 1, 9, 1),
    Name4 = c(3, 3, 3, 3))

list_data <- list(data1, data2, data3, data4)
```

I also have a list with an equal number of entries, each entry contains a vector of row positions in list_data:

```
rows1 <- c(1, 4)
rows2 <- c(1)
rows3 <- c(1, 3, 6)
rows4 <- c(2, 3)

list_rows <- list(rows1, rows2, rows3, rows4)
```

How can I subset each dataframe in `list_data` using the corresponding vector of row positions in `list_rows`?

Comment: Try `Map(function(x, y) x[y, ], list_data, list_rows)` or with `tidyverse`  `map2(list_data, list_rows, ~ .x[.y,])`

Comment: Incredible, thank @akrun. You should put it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With corresponding indices, a `base R` direction option is `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) x[y, ], list_data, list_rows) 
#[[1]]
#  ID Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
#1  1     3     4     6     8
#4  1     2     5     7     9

#[[2]]
#  ID Name4 Name2 Name3 Name1
#1  2     7     3     2     1

#[[3]]
#  ID Name3 Name1 Name4 Name2
#1  3     6     2     3     2
#3  3     6     2     3     2
#6  3     6     2     3     2

#[[4]]
#  ID Name2 Name3 Name1 Name4
#2  4     7     1     1     3
#3  4     7     1     9     3
```

---

Similar extraction can be done with `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(list_data, list_rows, ~ .x[.y,])
```

Or

```
map2(list_data, list_rows,  `[`, )
```

Comment: Actually, similar to this. But, instead of list `list_rows`. I have `vec`.`c(Name1, Name3, Name4)`. In the lsdf, these are columnnames for some ( like above), and part of ID column for others df's.

Comment: @user5249203  If it is `vec <- c(rows1, rows2, rows3, rows4)`, there is no way to differentiate which one comes from which vector unless it is named.  I would get the objects in a list `mget(ls(pattern = "^Name\\d+$"))` and use the same code

Comment: @user5249203  In this example, the number of elements in each 'rows1', 'rows2', are different.  Sorry,didn't see this comment earlier

Comment: @user5249203  Can you please comment regarding whether it is named or not

Comment: sorry, I just posted the Q here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122187/subset-list-of-multiple-dataframe-based-on-wither-row-or-column-match

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible solution using lapply:

```
f<-function(df,list_rows)
     {
       return(df[unlist(list_rows[df[1,1]]),])
     }

    lapply(list_data,f,list_rows=list_rows)
    [[1]]
      ID Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
    1  1     3     4     6     8
    4  1     2     5     7     9

    [[2]]
      ID Name4 Name2 Name3 Name1
    1  2     7     3     2     1

    [[3]]
      ID Name3 Name1 Name4 Name2
    1  3     6     2     3     2
    3  3     6     2     3     2
    6  3     6     2     3     2

    [[4]]
      ID Name2 Name3 Name1 Name4
    2  4     7     1     1     3
    3  4     7     1     9     3
```